# XlsxWriter set_column using variable from

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm using this function (i can not remember the author) to convert integer to column letter

```
def colnum_string(n):
    div = n
    string = ""
    while div > 0:
        module = (div-1) % 26
        string = chr(65 + module) + string
        div = int((div-module) / 26)
    return string
```

But, when I try to use the return to set the column size I'm getting error:

```
columna = colnum_string(1) + ':' + colnum_string(1)
worksheet.set_column(columna, 20)
```

Error:

```
  File "/share/MD0_DATA/Qweb/RollMBoToolP/src/main.py", line 78, in <module>
worksheet.set_column(columna, 20)
  File "/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 115, in column_wrapper
    _, col_1 = xl_cell_to_rowcol(cell_1)
  File "/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/utility.py", line 108, in xl_cell_to_rowcol
    col_str = match.group(2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: ***Tested with Python:3.4.2 and 2.7.9 - xlsxwriter:0.9.6***, no Error.
Please edit your Question with your used Versions.

Comment: You don't necessarily need an `A:Z` style string in `set_column()`. It also takes zero indexed `0, 25` style number parameters. See the docs for [`set_column()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-column).

Comment: Thanks, jmcnamara using index col,row works ok!